# Error when installing the express application generator

Tags: express

I recently installed node and express with the help of the mozilla tutorial. I am on the next step of installing the application generator, but when I run

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

in my terminal: I recieve the following errors:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamgusky/.npm/_logs/2018-02-17T20_26_53_688Z-debug.log
```

I've been googling this topic for an hour now and I am very new to using the terminal for web applications (this is for a school project), so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What platform? Linux, Mac?

Comment: @geoidesic I'm running this on mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The problem is that you aren't an administrator so you can't write to that folder. However it's considered a BAD IDEA to run `sudo npm install`. So what you need to do is to change the default install folder for npm global installation to one where you do have write permission.

See npm's documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.

And also see this useful article on github: https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/wiki/Installing-global-node-modules-(Linux-and-Mac)